# How to change TabLayout selected tab icon using ViewPager2

Tags: android

I use `FragmentStateAdapter`, `ViewPager2`, and `com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout`, and to set tab icon, I use `com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayoutMediator`

```
TabLayoutMediator(
    mTabActivity.tabLayout,
    mTabActivity.viewPager,
    TabLayoutMediator.TabConfigurationStrategy { tab, position ->
        when (mTabEnums[position]) {
            TabType.TAB_CONTACT -> tab.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_tab_contact)
            TabType.TAB_GROUPS -> tab.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_tab_groups)
            TabType.TAB_MESSAGES -> tab.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_tab_message)
            TabType.TAB_MAPS -> tab.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_tab_map)
            TabType.TAB_RECENTS -> tab.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_tab_recent)
            TabType.TAB_INCALL_LIST -> tab.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_tab_contact)
            TabType.TAB_INCALL_MAPS -> tab.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_tab_map)
        }
    }
).attach()
```

But how can I change icon of a selected tab?

I tried this, but `mViewPager` is a `ViewPager2` not a `ViewPager`, and code does not compile.

```
mTabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(
      new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(mViewPager) {

         @Override
         public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            super.onTabSelected(tab);
            int tabIconColor = ContextCompat.getColor(
                    ActivityTab.this, R.color.colorPrimary);
            tab.getIcon().setColorFilter(tabIconColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
         }

         @Override
         public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            super.onTabUnselected(tab);
            int tabIconColor = ContextCompat.getColor(
                    ActivityTab.this, R.color.colorAccent);
            tab.getIcon().setColorFilter(tabIconColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
         }

         @Override
         public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            super.onTabReselected(tab);
         }
      }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

This call back gives me the position of the selected tab

```
mTabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new   TabLayout.BaseOnTabSelectedListener() {
     @Override
     public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        Log.d(TAG,"selection "+tab.getPosition());
     }

     @Override
     public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

     }

     @Override
     public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

     }
  });
```

or in Kotlin

```
mTabActivity.tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(object :
    TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener {
    override fun onTabSelected(tab: TabLayout.Tab) {
        when (mTabEnums[tab.position])
        {
            TabType.TAB_CONTACT -> tab.icon =
                ContextCompat.getDrawable(mTabActivity,R.drawable.ic_tab_contact_green)
        }
    }

    override fun onTabUnselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab) {
        when (mTabEnums[tab.position])
        {
            TabType.TAB_CONTACT -> tab.icon =
                ContextCompat.getDrawable(mTabActivity,R.drawable.ic_tab_contact)
        }
    }

    override fun onTabReselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab) {

    }

})
```

Comment: This answer is right, just use tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() because setOnTabSelectedListener is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

You can add `app:tabIconColorTint` in your Layout-XML:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="?attr/colorOnSurface" android:state_selected="true" />
    <item android:alpha="0.60" android:color="?attr/colorOnSurface" />
</selector>
```

Comment: Are you sure this the color of the icon set to the tab, and not the tab indicator color? I use a vector for the icon.

Comment: There is no xml attribute `app:tabIconColorTint` for `TabLayout`, use `app:tabIconTint`, it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

TabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener() and TabLayout.BaseOnTabSelectedListener is deprecated.
Use this instead.

```java
tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(@NonNull TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        // change icon here
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
    }
});
```

Also if you just want to change the tab icon tint. Consider using this instead of setting a color filter:

```java
final int color = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.myColor);
DrawableCompat.setTint(tab.getIcon(), color);
```